# C++ virtual function from privately inherited class, promoted to public in derived class declaration

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, visibility, promotions

I have the following scheme:

```
class Interface
{
    virtual ~Interface() { }
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual void bar() const = 0;
}

//Interface is derived privately mostly for preventing upcast outside
class Derived : private Interface
{
public:
    void foo() const;
private:
    void bar() const;
}
```

It does not compile : `foo` is private. Is there any way to make it public without adding a dummy public function?

Comment: There is no way you can call `foo()` from `Derived`, as it is private. You have to make it protected

Comment: It compiles fine for me on MSVS 2013. I believe OP is simply overriding `foo` in `Interface` with the `foo` in `Derived`. The reason it didn't compile for me was because the destructor of `Interface` is `private`.

Comment: This will not even compile, as ~Interface() is private.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly valid, as far as the language is concerned, for a public member function in a derived class to override a private member function in the base class. Whether doing so is a good idea is a different question. And it certainly makes little sense for an abstract base class to have no public member functions.

The problem with your code is that `Interface` has a private destructor, making it impossible for derived classes to destroy their base class subobjects. `~Interface()` should be either protected or public.

Answer (score 0):

**No, there is not.**

Furthermore, even a dummy public function would require that `foo` in the base were `protected`, not `private`.

I would revisit your design. If the function is intended to be public, then why is it not `public`?

Answer (score -1):

It is not allowed to change the accessibility of an inherited member. If it was allowed, you would be able to derive from a class and make its private or protected members public, breaking the encapsulation.